# Cassandra 2.1.0-beta2: Invalid set literal for ColumnDefinition

Tags: cassandra

I'm trying out Cassandra 2.1.0-beta2 for nested user defined types. These are the structures that has been created through cqlsh 5.0.0:

```
CREATE TYPE channelsource(id text, sources set<text>);
CREATE TYPE primaryfeed(name text, type text, multisource channelsource);

CREATE TABLE somedata (
source text PRIMARY KEY, 
unitid text, 
dayssincebirth text, 
reporttime text,
somefeed primaryfeed
);
```

This sample insert fails:

```
INSERT INTO somedata (source, unitid, dayssincebirth, reporttime, somefeed)
VALUES('GFDS8-v1.2.3', 'xxxxxxxx-ABCD-1234-B8F9-11111177F4', '89', '13:02:39',
{'dha', 'foo', {'someid', {'aa', 'cc'}}});
```

With this error:

```
code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Invalid set literal for ColumnDefinition
{name=somefeed, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UserType
(bispace,7072696d61727966656564,6e616d65:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type,
74797065:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type,6d756c7469736f75726365:
org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UserType(bispace,6368616e6e656c736f75726365,6964
:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type,736f7572636573:
org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.SetType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type))),
 kind=REGULAR, componentIndex=0, indexName=null, indexType=null} of type primaryfeed"
```

Any pointers on what the correct syntax I should be using? I'm assuming that nested user defined types are supported in 2.1 onwards.

Answer (score 1):

You basically need to pass also the name of the fields, i.e.

```
{name: 'dha', type: 'foo', ...}
```

More details are in this article http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cql-in-2-1

*Note*: the syntax you used ( `{'val', 'val'}`) is the syntax for sets and that explains the error you are seeing.

Comment: Thank You for your prompt response, had gone through that article i was under the impression that only if it was an update i would need to specify the names of the columns, not for an insert.